# Assign and control Digital pin from String

Tags: arduino-uno, led, string, convert

Here is modified version of Blink example

```
#define D8  13

String p = "D8";

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(D8, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  byte pin[2];
  p.getBytes(pin, sizeof(pin)); 

  digitalWrite(D8, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(D8, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

D8 defined above is a byte of length 2. So LED turns on/off if I mention D8 on digitalWrite(D8, HIGH). Similarly I am getting the same byte D8 from `String p = "D8"`, and converting it into byte of length 2, but assigning `pin` to digitalWrite(pin, HIGH/LOW) doesn't works. Has anyone tried something similar before ? any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `digitalWrite(pin, value)` is expecting an `unsigned 8 bit integer` for the `pin` parameter ......... it is actually unclear what you are trying to do ....... also, ` doesn't works` does not describe what actually happens .... if you got an error, then why did you not say anything about it?

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ programs get compiled in multiple passes through various programs/steps. One of the first is the *C Preprocessor*, which handles the `#define` *preprocessor directive*.

It's basically a big find/replace function. After the preprocessor is done, anywhere you had `D8` outside of a string literal, would have the value `13`. It's not a variable or a string -- it's simply the number 13.

But the `String` `p`, which has content `"D8"` doesn't get replaced by the `#define` directive because it's part of a string, and the preprocessor doesn't modify strings in that way.

Also, `p` converted to a `byte` array of length 2 does not have anything like `13` as the value. It has `0x44` and `0x38` (or, in decimal, `68` (ASCII `'D'`) and `56` (ASCII `'8'`)). Disregarding that `digitalWrite()` and `pinMode()` do not accept byte arrays, only bytes, you are passing in a byte that doesn't represent pin 13.

If you want to assign the pin via a string, then you would need to use programming to examine the string and pick the right byte value, and each possible value would have to be explicitly enumerated and checked for.